# React.js typescript sweetalert error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sweetalert

i'm using React.js with Typescript and i'm having this error:

```
node_modules\@types\sweetalert\index.d.ts
error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'sweetAlert'.
```

dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts-ts": "2.8.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^21.1.6",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.51",
    "@types/react": "^16.0.22",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.1",
    "@types/sweetalert": "^1.1.28"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'sweetAlert'.

`sweetAlert` is written in TypeScript and you do not need `@types/sweetAlert` anymore.

## Fix

```
npm uninstall @types/sweetAlert
```

Profit